# Having trouble with graph3d installation in RStudio

Tags: r, installation

Trying to install **graph3d** I get an error message reproduced here

```
  > require("graph3d")

Loading required package: graph3d
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'graph3d'

    > version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.1                         
year           2017                        
month          06                          
day            30                          
svn rev        72865                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle               
>
```

On a different computer with an older version of R I get **no** error message

```
    > version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.5                         
year           2016                        
month          04                          
day            14                          
svn rev        70478                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
nickname       Very, Very Secure Dishes    

    > require("graph3d")
    >
```

Going back to the newer version and using install.packages command produces the message below

```
>install.packages("graph3d")
```

Installing package into `'C:/Users/XXXXXXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4'`
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :

```
 package 'graph3d' is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install it via devtools, that worked for me:

```
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kassambara/graph3d")
```